# multiple if statements at codeigniter model is unable to run more that one query

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i run multiple if statements on codeigniter model are unable to run more that one query?

here is queries on my model, they return a result only at 1st if the condition.

```
        if (isset($_POST['globalSearch'])) {
            $search_order = $_POST['globalSearch'];
            $this->db->where("m.material_request_id LIKE '%$search_order%'" , null , false);
        }
        if ($_POST['globalSearch'] == 'delivery') {
            $search_order = 3;
            $this->db->where("m.order_type" , $search_order );
        }
        if ($_POST['globalSearch'] == 'material') {
            $search_order = 2;
            $this->db->where("m.order_type" , $search_order );
        }   
        if ($_POST['globalSearch'] == 'type3') {
            $search_order = 1;
            $this->db->where("m.order_type" , $search_order );
        }
```

Comment: you need to execute the query in every if condition like $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array();

Comment: in every where clause you have to define that from which table you r getting data on which based